# Unity Error " Build path contains project built with "Create Visual Studio Solution""

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I get the unity error

```
Build path contains project built with "Create Visual Studio Solution" option, which is incompatible with current build settings
```

every time I try to add a script to my project.

I'm a noob to unity so there is probably a very simple answer, but I cant find anyone on stack overflow with the same problem.

-All settings are set to default

-using unity 2018.4.19f1

-nothing is changed other than adding a script.

-project is in 2d

Comment: Any chance your path has interesting non a-z0-9 characters?

Answer (score 0):

Cause of the problem: The path name saved during packaging has illegal characters.

[image]

Your path may contain offending characters. You need to set your packaging path to a-z0-9 characters.Hope it helps you.

Comment: ill try that thanks, sorry for the late rply

Comment: Unity 2018.4.19f1 doesn't have the option to change the package name in the player settings. where should I go to change it?

Comment: this didnt work sorry